# Proof for binary operation that is commutative and associative

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that if $*$ is an associative and commutative  binary operation on a set $S$, then $(a*b)*(c*d) =[(d*c)*a]*b$ for all $a,b,c,d \in S$ Assuming the associative law for triples only as in the definition $(x*y)*z=x*(y*z)$ for all $x,y,z \in S$

$(a * b) * (c * d)  = (b * a) * (d * c) = b * [a * (d * c)] = [(d * c) * a] * b$

Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That proof looks fine to me. You might want to write it with explanations for each equality, though, like this:
\begin{align}
(a * b) * (c * d)  &= (b * a) * (d * c) \text{, by commutativity of multiplication, in each factor}\\
&= b * [a * (d * c)] \text{, by associativity, applied to $x =b, y = a, z =(d*c)$}\\
&= [(d * c) * a] * b \text{, by commutatitivity}
\end{align}

Comment: will do! thank ou